What happens to existing leases after the migration to Agile Coretime?
Seeking clarification here about the following claim (https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-agile-coretime#when-and-how-can-i-renew-my-legacy-lease):

When and how can I renew my legacy lease?
The slots.leases are migrated to leases in the broker pallet with an expiry timeslice that corresponds to your original expiry block. When the lease expires, the parachain has a core until the end of the sales period that it expired in. After that, the interlude period starts. In that sale period you can renew your bulk coretime by calling renew on the lease's core. The price will be charged and will be equal to the market price of a bulk core in that sale.
For more details, check out our technical guide.
Will all leases be migrated to Agile Coretime?
If your team has a lease secured by the time Agile Coretime launches, they will also have a lease on Agile Coretime and the right for renewal when the lease expires. If the lease of your project would only start after Agile Coretime launch (not yet active at launch time), the lease will be cancelled and your locked KSM refunded. You will need to purchase and assign coretime.
Note: Your lease will also be canceled and refunded, in case it is not continuous, as leases with “holes” are not supported by Agile Coretime.

Following up on chain with Zeitgeist's current lease, I'm getting this result when calling slots.leases(2092):
[
  [
    13UVJyLnbVp77Z2t6qosP5EzMw2m69hTbhvbUaxbmoVWbVDS
    372,705,993,563,081
  ]
  [
    15Q7heNtPy5vaZ79c3eUt7M42Ao3okf7PKKdRDULBz3Z4UyF
    3,690,000,000,000
  ]
  [
    15Q7heNtPy5vaZ79c3eUt7M42Ao3okf7PKKdRDULBz3Z4UyF
    3,690,000,000,000
  ]
  [
    15Q7heNtPy5vaZ79c3eUt7M42Ao3okf7PKKdRDULBz3Z4UyF
    3,690,000,000,000
  ]
  [
    15Q7heNtPy5vaZ79c3eUt7M42Ao3okf7PKKdRDULBz3Z4UyF
    3,690,000,000,000
  ]
  [
    15Q7heNtPy5vaZ79c3eUt7M42Ao3okf7PKKdRDULBz3Z4UyF
    3,690,000,000,000
  ]
  [
    15Q7heNtPy5vaZ79c3eUt7M42Ao3okf7PKKdRDULBz3Z4UyF
    3,690,000,000,000
  ]
  [
    15Q7heNtPy5vaZ79c3eUt7M42Ao3okf7PKKdRDULBz3Z4UyF
    3,690,000,000,000
  ]
  [
    15Q7heNtPy5vaZ79c3eUt7M42Ao3okf7PKKdRDULBz3Z4UyF
    3,690,000,000,000
  ]
]

This is the result of Zeitgeist extending their lease without gaps and without swapping for another two years. Note that the lease extension was not reached when Agile Coretime was deployed.
First Question. Would this entire lease be considered active? Or only the first lease period of it? Or something else entirely? How much coretime should Zeitgeist expect to receive now that Agile Coretime is deployed?
Second Question. Now that Agile Coretime is deployed, why can I even still see this lease? Weren't leases supposed to be cancelled?
Furthermore, checking the code, I can only find this, which doesn't seem to support that any lease (active or otherwise) gets more than one core assigned for one region (https://github.com/polkadot-fellows/runtimes/blob/e6b9132701df4311e7d6331e3a9e051ae8de0104/relay/polkadot/src/coretime_migration.rs#L169-L183):
    for (core, para_id) in legacy_paras.into_iter().enumerate() {
        let r = parachains_assigner_coretime::Pallet::<T>::assign_core(
            CoreIndex(core as u32),
            now,
            vec![(CoreAssignment::Task(para_id.into()), PartsOf57600::FULL)],
            None,
        );
        if let Err(err) = r {
            log::error!(
                "Creating assignment for existing para failed: {:?}, error: {:?}",
                para_id,
                err
            );
        }
    }

Maybe I'm misreading the code though. This is what I'm seeing on-chain (coretimeAssignmentProviders.coreDescriptors(None):
    [
      0xc2d9675cf95dcf1a95ee00f17cffed606f156f906fa1979fba28e48007d385bb
    ]
    {
      queue: null
      currentWork: {
        assignments: [
          [
            {
              Task: 2,092
            }
            {
              ratio: 57,600
              remaining: 57,600
            }
          ]
        ]
        endHint: null
        pos: 1
        step: 57,600
      }
    }

Third Question. I'm assuming this core is only available for one region. Is that correct? How could I tell? Am I reading the code above wrong?
Edit/Fourth Question. What is the definition of "active lease" exactly?
